# why selecting multiple elements with querySelector returns null?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select two HTML tags with document.querySelector, but when using console.log the return is null. I tried using document.getElementById , but the result is the same.

Javascript:

```
  const startTime = document.querySelector(`.time-start-${name}`)
  console.log(startTime); //shows

  const endTime = document.querySelector(`.time-end-${name}`)
  console.log(endTime); //doens't shows
  //Shows the total time.
  const uiStartTime = document.querySelector(`.${name}-start-time > span`);
  console.log(uiStartTime); //shows

  // shows the progress bar
  const uiProgressBar = document.querySelector(`.${name}-bar-fill`);

  // shows the current time
  const uiTime = document.getElementById(`time-${name}`);
  console.log(uiTime);
  // shows the starting time

  // shows the added or removed time
  const uiAddedTime = document.querySelector(`.update-${name}-time`);
  console.log(uiAddedTime);
```

html:

```
<p class="label-3">Starts:</p>
        <span class="time-start-peg-1">10</span>
      <p class="label-1">Ends:</p>
        <span id="time-end-peg-1">10</span>
        <div class="peg-1-start-time total-time">
           <p class="label-2">Length:</p>
            <span id="total-time-1">-</span>
            <span id="update-peg-1-time">+10</span>
        </div>
        <div class="peg-1-bar">
          <div class="peg-1-bar-fill">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="peg-1-timer">
          <span id="time-peg-1">-</span>
        </div>
```

to specify the update-peg-1-time and time-end-peg-1 are the ones that don't show, is there something that I am missing?

Comment: It is unclear what the value of the variable `name` is from your snippet. This could be the issue.

Comment: `const endTime = document.querySelector(\`.time-end-${name}\`)` this should be `const endTime = document.querySelector(\`#time-end-${name}\`)` because it's ID not CLASS

Comment: same here: `const uiAddedTime = document.querySelector(\`.update-${name}-time\`);` should be `const uiAddedTime = document.querySelector(\`#update-${name}-time\`);`

Comment: @GrafiCode the endTime is fixed, but the uiAddedTime still doesn't shows, even after specifying the id. thanks for the fix!

Comment: @Jhona seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/k4nm1jrx/

Comment: @GrafiCode yes, I just had to update the other elements, thanks for the assist!